# Downvoting and Closing

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I've been noticing quite a few questions being downvoted as well as vote-closed. In pretty well every situation, the close votes are pretty fair. Many of these questions however are salvageable.

This question for example:
https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/determine-how-much-an-individual-will-save-depending-on-varying-values-in-their
As it is now, it is a basic copy paste homework question not formatted particularly well.

A close vote is preferred in this situation because it a lot easier to undo. A question will show up in the review queue as edited after closing and people can decide what to do. A down vote will remain their long after a question changes from a bad to a good question.

Don't downvote questions which could be simply closed.

Comment: Also the issue of downvoting and voting to close without any comments still persists, like it did earlier
http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/174/adding-comments-along-with-downvotes
http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/more-downvoting-issues
I think if you have time enough to pass intelligent judgement you have time enough to write a short comment. Apologies if you think this might be better discussed in a separate question, I thought it appropriate because downvoting and closing are exactly the areas affected.

Answer (score 4):

Down votes can be changed as well once the question has been edited. Though I confess that I agree that this is less likely to be reversed since the individual must see it again and then undownvote (or upvote) it as opposed to being handled by the community.

If an edited question that you think is appropriate for the site has downvotes then you should upvote it. IMO, we need more votes whether they are up or down votes.

Comment: I'd rather more of both. I think we should be saving the down votes for the bad, irrelevant questions and closing those the are salvageable.